# Does repeated fields in protobuffers keep the order they are inserted?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Consider the following message.

```
message example { 
   repeated string text; 
}
```

Let's say that in C++ I have a list of string that I insert into the text field of example:

```
exemple aMessage; 
std::list<std::string> aList = ... ;
for (std::string anStr : aList) 
{
    aMessage.add_text(anStr);
}
```

Later on if I access text of the my message, will that field be ordered in the same way as my list?  What about when I serialize it and send it off somewhere?

Will the order stay constant?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, repeated fields retain the order of items.

From [Google's Protocol Buffers encoding specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional):

> The order of the elements with respect to each other is preserved when parsing, though the ordering with respect to other fields is lost.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what the second part of the sentence means.

Comment: @AlperenAYDIN If you have `repeated string textA` and `repeated string textB`, the order within `textA` and `textB` arrays is kept. However, you could technically create a message that is `textA[0], textB[0], textA[1], textB[1]` in encoded form, but after decoding and recoding it will look like `textA[0], textA[1], textB[0], textB[1]`.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: While the question is tagged with C, the ordering is part of the protocol, so it applies for implementation in any language.